# Access my returned data from an RxJs Observable method call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

(NEWB) How can I modify my `updateUserProfile()` Observable method in my `service`, so that I can get access to the returned data? I would like to set the values of my `user` in my `service`, and not in my `component`. Is there perhaps an additional callback function or operator I can use?

**This is my User Object:**

```
  user: User = {
    user: {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      id_number: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      phone: '',
      notes: '',
      ricaAddress: {
        street_number: '',
        street_name: '',
        building_name: '',
        floor_level: '',
        unit_number: '',
        suburb: '',
        city: '',
        province: '',
        postal_code: '',
        country: ''
      }
    }
  };
```

**This is my `updateProfile()` call in my `component`:**

```
  updateProfile() {
    this.userService
      .updateUserProfile(this.user)
      .subscribe(
        response => {},
        err => this.handleError(err),
        () => console.log('complete')
      );
  }
```

**This is the `updateUserProfile()` method in my service I would like to modify**:

```
  updateUserProfile(user): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions2 = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        apiKey: 'xEr4slh6wdngI-imBb9t8sm4JLY-e1yQz7Tmo7S2A',
        key: '6f4962c7-0706-4cf7-b7ce-0b7dc75fcc57',
        Authorization: this.userToken
      })
    };

    return this.http
      .put(this.apiUrl + 'users' + 'user_id', user, httpOptions2)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `map` pipe in order to return a new, updated, object. In your service:

```js
return this.http
  .put(this.apiUrl + 'users' + 'user_id', user, httpOptions2)
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      // return a new object from here
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

The return value of `map`'s callback can directly be accessed in your component then.

Comment: Or tap if you don't want to modify the response

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm -- yeah, absolutely. I thought the statement _I would like to set the values of my user in my service_ was related to change the data. That's why preferred `map` in my answer.